# How can I change the background color of columns in Laravel-admin?

Tags: laravel, laravel-9, laravel-admin

I'm currently working on Laravel-admin project with laravel9.

For instance, If the value = 'error', I want to change the background color of the column.
Something like this pic:

[image]

My code is this:

```
        $grid->column('title')->display(function ($title, $column) {
            if ($title !== 'error') {
                return $title;
            }
            return $column->setAttributes(['style' => 'background-color:red;']);
        });
```

But seems like I can't use `setAttributes()` method on `$column`.
Also If I use `setAttributes(['style' => 'background-color:red;'])` the column name(In this case title) become red as well.
Any advice would be appreciated.

I read the Laravel-admin document and searched for a solution for hours but I couldn't find any good info.